# Create a line from another line

Tags: qgis, line

The orange line is continuous, but corresponds to the union of several lines.
[image]

What I would like to do is to join the lines into a single line until it collides with a green point as shown in the picture.

[image]

Is it possible with any QGIS tool?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Dissolve` your lines, then run `multi- to single-part` in order to separate each continuous line from the others, then `split lines by points` using the green points.

Comment: where can i find those options?

Comment: Have a look in the toolbox.

Comment: Thank you for your help.